# Android Development How Do I Use The Twitch Api?

Tags: android, twitch

Hi I really need some sources for using the twitch api on android as the twitch api site or their forum do not have any useful information on how to integrate it into an android app.

Essentially I need to use the login and chat for a specific channel.

Comment: In the docs, they have described to you about the parameters required to hit their web service. You should see first how to make a web service call and use outh in android. Then you will feel easy with the API.

Comment: ok thanks very much :)